# Python: How to import variables from script A to script B, that are created during the execution of A?

Tags: python

I am executing script A that dynamically sets some variables, which are defined as global at the beginning of the code.

I would like to import these variables from a script B, using something similar to `from script_a import var1, var2`. Passing these variables as an argument to script B, unfortunately is not an option, as some other scripts need to import them later on too. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Passing data between processes can not be archived with `import`. And options would be to write the data to a file (in JSON for example) and read it in the other process(es).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best option is to wrap the code in script a into a function like this:

```
def wrapper():
   ...existing code...
   return stuff
if __name__ == "__main__":
  wrapper()
```

then import and call the wrapper from script b.

```
from scripta import wrapper
vars = wrapper()
```